# Change Parent Node to Another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for dumb question. I've met some answers here early on, but now I can't find them.
I have (e.g.):

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="move">
        1
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
```

What is the right way to change parent of `#move` from `#div1` to `#div2` without loosing anything I've binded to `#move` (e.g. `.click()` bindings an other stuff)?

Example code:

```
$('#move').animate({ //hide
        width: 'toggle',
        height: 'toggle',
      }, 1000, function() {
        $('#div2').prepend($(this)); //move (when animation finished)
        $(this).animate({ //show again
            width: 'toggle',
            height: 'toggle',
             }, 1000);

});
```

That seems working, still I don't know if I have done this right, (e.g. I don't remove manually `$(this)` from the old parent. Probably jQuery does it for me, because I don't see that node on old place when I use the browser debugger).

Comment: There are no dumb questions :)

Comment: You should use `.prepend(this);` instead even it will change nothing to your code

Comment: @Kiran Ruth R "... but there are dumb people"? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is correct, you don't have to add to a div somewhere, and then remove the original... jQuery will move the div for you. In fact, you have to be very specific by using the clone() function if you want to make a copy.

So the prepend, append, after, insert, etc. functions will move the div with everything attached to it around the DOM. I'm pretty sure it also keeps the click-bindings...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll close Q a bit later, just in case if someone knows better solution or any issues with that approach.